# Google Sign-in with control over cookie expiration date

Tags: openid, google-signin, openid-connect, google-oauth, google-openid

I use [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web) and it's pretty nice. Here's how I render a sign-in button:

```
gapi.signin2.render('signin2', {
    onsuccess: function(googleUser) {
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        ajaxPostForServerSideLogin(id_token).then(function() {
            // YAY! Signed in on the server too
        })
    }
})
```

The problem is that I set the cookie expiration date on the server to X minutes and after clicking around on the site after X+1 minutes, I want the user to be logged out and have to log in again.

Instead the rendered Google Sign-In button automatically triggers the `onsuccess` (with a valid `googleUser` object) if I'm still logged in to Google.

**How can I tell Google Sign-In to NOT remember my users' session for more than X minutes?**

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to pass OIDC's `prompt=login` [parameter](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) to the [`signIn()` function](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsigninoptions) to require login confirmation.

Another way might be to explicitely call Google's [sign out method](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user):

```
<a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
<script>
  function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
      console.log('User signed out.');
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The `render` function does not accept a `prompt` parameter. :(
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapi.signin2.render

Comment: Also, signing out is not an option. But it's how I'll have to hack it. The server decides that the session cookie has expired and that's not an event. Just a matter of time. Even less an event in JavaScript.

Comment: @PeterBengtsson my google signin token always expires after ~1hour. How to set expire to like 1year?